# How can I run a env variables on bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I've learned about pipelines with bitbucket and I want to make a new one to upload my react application (bootstrapped with create-react-app) and uploaded to an Amazon S3 bucket.

I made a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file like this one

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Installing dependencies
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - rm -rf package-lock.json
          - rm -f node_modules
          - yarn add
    - step:
        name: Build
        script:
          - yarn build
```

When Bitbucket runs it, it shows me the next error message

```
env-cmd -f .env.production.local react-scripts build
Error: Unable to locate env file at location (.env.production.local)
```

This is it because in my package.json I use env-cmd to read my environment variables for the building script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f .env.development.local react-scripts start",
    "build": "env-cmd -f .env.production.local react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

But I don't know how to read that environment variables (localized inside of my .env files) in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml file

How can I get that?

Comment: you have to create .env.development.local file in react root directory

Comment: did you solve this??

Comment: You need to add those secret keys from GUI.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never...

.env, .env.production.local, or whatever file name you want. Interchangable.

first encode you .env file:

```
base64 -w 0 .env > envout.txt
```

Then add the contents of envout.txt to a repository variable in bitbucket $ENV_ENCODED or similar

Add decode command to your pipeline:

```
echo $ENV_ENCODED | base64 -d > .env
```

Extra info:

1. this needs to be done as one step, so include it just before your build
2. if the command is not found, use build image with base64
3. Other option is to include .env in docker image that you host on a secure service like AWS ECR and pull the image from there, and it will have your .env file
4. If someone is able to download build agent as artifact, they will be able to view the contents of your .env. This is more of a deterrent than the most secure option.
5. adding `- cat .env` as a step would validate the process, but maybe use fake .env

I would also recommend doing your installation and build in the same step. I've ran into issues where generated files (especially .env) are different between steps.

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Installing dependencies and Build
        caches:
          - node
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - rm -rf package-lock.json
          - rm -f node_modules
          - yarn add
          - echo $ENV_ENCODED | base64 -d > .env
          - yarn build
```